# Futures Historical Tick Size

Tags: futures, market-data, tick

I understand for some futures contracts, tick size does change from time to time. Does anyone know where to get historical tick size changes?

Comment: It seems that you specialize in asking very difficult questions :)

Comment: For example the tick size for 2 year treasury futures (ZT) changed on January 13, 2019 https://www.cmegroup.com/notices/clearing/2018/05/Chadv18-192.html But I don't know any way to find all tick changes for all futures... it seems a very difficult task

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at press releases from exchanges. I'm not aware of any centralized repository of data on changes in tick size. On the upside, they don't happen very often. :)